# Bash to multithread multiple files

Tags: bash

I have some files, about 10 (variable), each with 2000 lines of code. 
I have some function that will read each line of a document and do something with it.

I am trying to execute all of the files at the same time with a multithreaded process. I am trying to use Xargs for this, but I'm not sure how it would handle multiple indetermined files (they all have a similar name though: segmentA, segmentB etc etc).

Any suggestions?

Edit:
For further clarification, the function takes a document, and reads each line and sends each line to a solr server.

Comment: What do you mean by "function"? How do you run the process for a single file?

Comment: so the function basically takes a file, and runs through each line and sends it to a solr server. I left that out so not to make the problem more complicated that it had to be. I'll put this in the edit though :)

Comment: For some reason, my boss doesnt want it because we have to download the service first...

Comment: Use `xargs -P n` where `n` is the max number of parallel processes.

Comment: but how would I run each file separately (im a bit new to bash commands).